# $I(X;Z | Y ) = I(Z; Y | X) − I(Z; Y ) + I(X;Z)$

Tags: information-theory

I am working on the following exercise from information theory:

> Let $X, Y, Z : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be random variables. Show that
>   $$I(X;Z | Y ) = I(Z; Y | X) − I(Z; Y ) + I(X;Z).$$
>
> Remark: $H$ means entropy and $I$ means mutual information. Mutual information for two discrete RVs $X, Y$is given by,
>
> $$I(X;Y) := \sum_{x,y} P_{XY}(x,y) \log
> {P_{XY}(x,y) \over P_X(x) P_Y(y)}
> = E_{P_{XY}} \log{P_{XY} \over P_X P_Y}
> \, .$$
>   , where $P_{XY}(x,y)$ is their mutual probability distribution. The following identities were proven in class:
>
> $$I(X;X) = H(X)$$
>
> \begin{align}
>    I(X;Y) &= H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y) \\
>           &= H(X)-H(X \mid Y) \\
>           &= H(Y)-H(Y \mid X) \\
>           &= I(Y, X)
> \end{align}
>
> $$I(X;Y \mid Z) = H(X \mid Z) - H(X \mid Y,Z) = H(X \mid Y,Z) = H(Y \mid Z) - H(Y \mid X,Z)$$

I do not see how I could prove this. I tried to replace the $I$'s (mutual information) with $H$'s (entropy) with formulas like

$$I(X; Z \mid Y) = H(X \mid Y) - H(X \mid Z,Y)$$

but it just does not work out. Could you help me?

Comment: Maybe if you explained what your notation means? What is I and ;

Comment: @badatmath: $I$ stands for mutual information and $H$ is the entropy. I thought this was the standard notation.

Comment: What does mutual information mean

Comment: It is defined at wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information

Comment: Most people can probably solve it if they knew what it meant

Comment: Why would people Google stuff to answer your question? A question should be self contained

Comment: OK, I will make an edit

Comment: $$
\operatorname{I}(X;Y) = \sum_{y \in \mathcal Y} \sum_{x \in \mathcal X}
    { p_{(X,Y)}(x,y) \log{ \left(\frac{p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)}{p_X(x)\,p_Y(y)} \right) }}
$$

$$
\operatorname{I}(X;Y|Z)  =  \sum_{z\in \mathcal{Z}} \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} \sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}
    {p_Z(z)\, p_{X,Y|Z}(x,y|z) 
        \log\left[\frac{p_{X,Y|Z}(x,y|z)}{p_{X|Z}\,(x|z)p_{Y|Z}(y|z)}\right]},
$$
$$
\operatorname{I}(X;Y|Z) = \sum_{z\in \mathcal{Z}} \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} \sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}
      p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) \log \frac{p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)p_{Z}(z)}{p_{X,Z}(x,z)p_{Y,Z}(y,z)}.
$$

Comment: Looks like it will be moving things in and out of logs and using Bayes theorem

Comment: do you know chain rule for mutual information ?

Comment: @P.Quinton: Now that you say it; yes I do it was the last theorem we did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $I(Z:Y) +I(Z:X|Y) = I(Z:XY) = I(X:Z) + I(Z:Y|X)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not get it. Where do these equatios come from? Is it the chain rule for mutual information?

Comment: Yes, this is indeed. Look at the Some Identities section in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mutual_information